# align one div above two divs in flex box container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have four divs in a flex box. I want to align the forth div `class="details"` above **second** and **third** div. I tried but not successful. Please help!!!

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: space-between;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 45%;
}
.flex-container > div {
  color: white;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  line-height: 75px;
  
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.calu
{
  height: 49%;
  align-self:flex-end;  
}

.calu_ {background-color: #C90399;}
.punjj_ {background-color: #F44336;}
.punjj
{
  height: 48%;
  align-self:flex-end;
  
}

.bajet {background-color: #FE0857;}
.details
{
  flex-basis: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
  font-size: 15px;
  
}

.vertical 
{
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px #ccc;
}

.progress {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}   

.progress-bar {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgb(100 100 100 / 60%);
}
```

```html
<p><h1>The align-self Property</h1></p>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class= "progress vertical" >1
      <div class="progress-bar bajet"  style="height: 35.19%;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class= "progress vertical calu">2
      <div class="progress-bar calu_"  style="height: 38.65%;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class= "progress vertical punjj">3
      <div class="progress-bar punjj_"  style="height: 31.65%;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="details" style="background-color:#90EE90;">4</div>
</div>
```

Please see the sample

[image]

Comment: Do you mean *before* the second and third divs?

Comment: No, above the second and third div, not before. The forth div must be above the second and third div. Thank You!!!

Comment: Because you want to position the elements across two axes it seems `display: grid` would be a better fit than `flex`.

Comment: Please consider my answer below. It's quiet easy to do what he wants with `display:flex`

Comment: As already commented, from your actual structure, this is a grid layout: you could start from : https://jsfiddle.net/7xce10va/

Comment: This post has long been answerd (plenty of different solutions). It should be marked as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably simpler and more efficient to use grid layout in this case.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 130px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.progress.vertical:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.calu {
  grid-row: 4 / -1;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  background-color: #C90399;
}

.punjj {
  grid-row: 4 / -1;
  grid-column: 5 / 7;
  background-color: #C90399;
}

.details {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
  background-color: #C90399;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.6);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.flex-container>div {
  line-height: 75px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.bajet {
  background-color: #FE0857;
}

.calu_ {
  background-color: #C90399;
}

.punjj_ {
  background-color: #F44336;
}

.vertical {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px #ccc;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.progress-bar {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgb(100 100 100 / 60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="progress vertical">1
    <div class="progress-bar bajet" style="height: 35.19%;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress vertical calu">2
    <div class="progress-bar calu_" style="height: 38.65%;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress vertical punjj">3
    <div class="progress-bar punjj_" style="height: 31.65%;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="details" style="background-color:#90EE90;">4</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7naezLkd/)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and maybe a dirty solution could be `position: absolute` for your fourth item. Add a relative position to the parent `.flex-container` and position your details like u wish.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: space-between;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 45%;
  position: relative;
}
.flex-container > div {
  color: white;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  line-height: 75px;
  
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.calu
{
  height: 49%;
  align-self:flex-end;  
}

.calu_ {background-color: #C90399;}
.punjj_ {background-color: #F44336;}
.punjj
{
  height: 48%;
  align-self:flex-end;
  
}

.bajet {background-color: #FE0857;}

.flex-container .details {
    height: 60%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 40%;
    width: 60%;
}

.vertical 
{
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px #ccc;
}

.progress {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}   

.progress-bar {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 6px rgb(100 100 100 / 60%);
}
```

```html
<p><h1>The align-self Property</h1></p>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class= "progress vertical" >1
      <div class="progress-bar bajet"  style="height: 35.19%;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class= "progress vertical calu">2
      <div class="progress-bar calu_"  style="height: 38.65%;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class= "progress vertical punjj">3
      <div class="progress-bar punjj_"  style="height: 31.65%;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="details" style="background-color:#90EE90;">4</div>
</div>
```

For a solution purely with `display: flex;` you have to adjust your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to achieve?
[image]

Therefore you have to put your "floating" div inside an container which has
`display` set to `flex` and `justify-content` set to `center`.
Cheers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .a {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .ba {
            display:flex;
            width:25%;
            height:100%;
            background-color:red;
        }
        
        .bb {
            display:flex;
            width:75%;
            height:100%;
            flex-direction:column;
        }
        
        .ca{
            display:flex;
            width:100%;
            height:50%;
            flex-direction:column;
            justify-content:center;
        }
        
        .cb{
            display:flex;
            width:100%;
            height:50%;
            flex-direction:row;
        }
        
        .da{
            display:flex;
            width:100%;
            height:50%;
            background-color:green;
        }
        
        .db{
            display:flex;
            width:50%;
            height:100%;
            background-color:blue;
        }
        
        .dc{
            display:flex;
            width:50%;
            height:100%;
            background-color:pink;
        }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="ba">
        </div>
        <div class="bb">
            <div class="ca">
                <div class="da">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cb">
                <div class="db">
                </div>
                <div class="dc">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```